# Помогите с WPF, Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, binding, path

У меня есть несколько `Image` и `Button`, они динамически (через код) добавляются в `WrapPanel` или в `StackPanel`, я хочу связать в коде: `Source` Картинки и `Content` Кнопки, как мне это сделать? Мне почти это удалось но осталась преграда со свойством `Path`, мне в `Source` нужно передать просто `logo`, а не `logo.(...)`. В общем что нужно прописать в Path если никакого свойства передавать не нужно, а нужно передать именно logo?

```
Image img = new Image() { Height = 35, Width = 35 };
BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
var brush = new ImageBrush();
logo.BaseUri = null;
logo.BeginInit();
logo.UriSource = new Uri(@"/images/"+d.value+".png", UriKind.Relative);
logo.EndInit();

Binding bind = new Binding();
bind.Source = logo;
bind.Path = new PropertyPath("");
bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, bind);

stack2.Children.Add(img);
```

Comment: Почему вы отказываетесь от работы с XAML? Ведь в предыдущем вашем вопросе я вам сказал почему ваш подход плох, я бы на вашем месте прислушался бы и сделал все по человечески.  Если не умеете, не стесняйтесь этого, мы вам с радостью поможем, но должно быть желание делать правильно! Сейчас вы сами себе палки в колеса всовываете...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня не так много времени чтобы разбирнаться с этим, потомучто прийдется переписывать весь проект, да и вникнуть сразу не удастся, мне осталось доделать лишь этот этап, а дальше если вдруг мне опять понадобится сделать чтото подобное, то я уже точно послушаю ваш совет

Comment: @Bulson а работа с API вместо бд пойдет?)))0

Comment: Ну так что, дельных советов не будет? :C

Comment: Что значит "связать в коде: Source Картинки и Content Кнопки"? В коде вообще не вижу где создается кнопка.

Comment: А если так: `bind.Path = new PropertyPath(".");`?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте передать "this".
В XAML у меня подобный трюк прокатывал.